# Hypothesis Test For Independence in Trials?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, independence

[I had asked this question over on Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861359/hypothesis-test-for-independence-in-trials) but I was wondering if could get any interesting feedback here as well (at the time of this question I haven't received an answer on Math exchange either)

## Problem

Let's say you have virtual cases in a video game, and each case has one of four distinct items inside. Let's say the items are:

- $A$ with general probability $0.4$
- $B$ with general probability $0.3$
- $C$ with general probability $0.2$
- $D$ with general probability $0.1$

However, there is rumor that these cases are programmed so that you are less likely to obtain duplicate items, as in, when opening a lot of cases, if you open $B$ in one case, for example, the probability of opening $B$ on the very next case is less than what it was originally, $0.3$

I was wondering how I would be able to test that rumor using a hypothesis test.

**My guess / Attempt**

Seeing as how $A$ is the most common item, I would use that one for my hypothesis test and test

$$H_0: P(A_k) = P(A_k | A_{k-1})$$

That is, the probability of opening $A$ on the $k^{th}$ case is the same as the probability of opening $A$ on the $k^{th}$ case given we just opened $A$ the case before

Is this a good / viable way to test what I want? And how would I proceed from here after gathering data? Would it be similar to testing for a population proportion?

Thanks for any help given

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one way to go about the problem is to consider a [Wald–Wolfowitz runs test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) or a similar non-parametric test.

If you define the two events A and not A, then the test should be applicable.

Comment: Doing a little research on the runs test, I actually learned that there is an extension of it to $k$ categories rather than being strictly binary. At first I didn't think a runs test could be applicable but now I think it is one way to go for this. Thanks!